# How to Run a jQuery or JavaScript Before Page Start to Load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that I want to run before the page start to load. The script checks the value of a variable and depending on the value  redirect the user to a new page.

I can successfully check the variable and redirect if needed but the page still loads and display empty page but then quickly redirects to the other page. I don't want that empty page to be displayed on the page at all before the redirect.

Thank you,
Ver

Comment: This wouldn't be an issue if you used a server side script (like php) to do the redirecting.

Comment: How are you doing it at the moment?

Answer (score 27):

Hide the body with css then show it after the page is loaded:

CSS:

```
html { visibility:hidden; }
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
});
```

The page will go from blank to showing all content when the page is loaded, no flash of content, no watching images load etc.

Comment: This is the coolest thing ever! I've been looking for this for a long time. It totally transforms the navigation of the site from page to page. Feels much smoother.

Comment: Beautiful idea, thanks !

Comment: The best solution ever

Answer (score 11):

```
<head>
  <script>
    if(condition){
      window.location = "http://yournewlocation.com";
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  ...
</body>
```

This will force the checking of condition and the change in url location before the page renders anything. It is worth noting that you will specifically want to do this before the call to the jQuery library so you can avoid all that library loading. Some might also argue that this would be better placed in a wrapper method and called so here is that method:

```
function redirectHandler(condition, url){
  if(condition){
    window.location = url;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

That would allow you to check multiple conditions and redirect to different locations based on it:

```
if(redirectHandler(nologgedin, "/login.php")||redirectHandler(adminuser, "/admin.php"));
```

or if you only need it to run once and only once, but you like having nothing in the global namespace:

```
(function(condition, url){
  if(condition)window.location=url;
})(!loggedin, "/login.asp");
```

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you are using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Your code here
 });
```

Try this instead:

```
window.onload = function(){  }
```

Comment: Yes I am using $(document).ready(function(){
   // Your code here
 }); this function only.
Is There any possible to do that in javascript

Comment: Code within `$(document).ready()` is run after your page is read, but before additional assets (e.g. images) are finished downloading. You *will* see something on the screen before scripts wrapped in `$(document).ready()` are run.

Answer (score 8):

Don't use $(document).ready() just put the script directly in the head section of the page. Pages are processed top to bottom so things at the top are processed first.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want anything to display before the redirect, then you will need to use some **server side** scripting to accomplish the task before the page is served. The page has already begun loading by the time your Javascript is executed on the **client side**.

If Javascript is your only option, your best best is to make your script the first .js file included in the `<head>` of your document.

Instead of Javascript, I recommend setting up your redirect logic in your Apache or nginx server configuration.

- Apache's [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)
- nginx's [HttpRewriteModule documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpRewriteModule)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
window.onload = function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation(true);
    window.location.href="http://www.google.com";
};
```

Good luck  ;)

Comment: The load event fires at the end of the document loading process including its content (images, css, scripts, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Try the unload event. The unload event is sent to the window element when the user navigates away from the page.

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
    //do something
});
```