# How to run jQuery before loading page?

Tags: jquery, html

I have many images on site and some scripts on it. But scripts can run only after loading whole page. How to accelerate this?

Comment: Put the javascript in the <head>, that will get it to run before the other stuff is loaded. It is not always good, depends on what you want to do. Your javascipt might also be set to run only when the document is ready.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Run a jQuery or JavaScript Before Page Start to Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930199/how-to-run-a-jquery-or-javascript-before-page-start-to-load)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //code here
});
```

will run a script when the document structure is ready, but before all of the images have loaded.

if you want to run script before the document structure is ready, just put your code anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes if you only use `$(document).ready()`, there will be a **flash** of content.

To avoid the flash, you can **hide the body with css then show it after the page is loaded**.

1. Add the line below to your CSS:

   ```
   html { visibility:hidden; }
   ```
2. And these to your JS:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     //your own JS code here

     document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
   });
   ```

Then the page will go from blank to showing all content when the page is loaded, **no flash of content, no watching images load etc**.

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28129658/9522354), thanks to the author.

Answer (score 0):

Load the images after the page loads?

It may depends on what kind of jquery code you're trying to run--what specifically are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //code here
});
```

and put the jQuery-Script tags at the end of the document.

`.ready` fires when the DOM is ready (which does not mean that the images are already loaded).

Answer (score 0):

If your JavaScript does any work on your Dom elements, then you have to wait until the page loads.

If you need to run the scripts before the image are loaded, you can always lazy load the images. That way you don't have to wait for the images to load.

Lazy loading is basically loading the images through JavaScript, so you can control when they load.